# Codeigniter 3 user guide compile

Tags: windows, python-2.7, user-guide, codeigniter-3

I'm missing one step on compiling codeigniter 3 user_guide in windows.
I followed the steps described [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/user_guide_src).

**Installation**

Step 1 - Install easy_install

Step 2 - easy_install sphinx

Step 3 - easy_install sphinxcontrib-phpdomain

Step 4 - Install the CI Lexer which allows PHP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript syntax highlighting in code examples (see cilexer/README)

Step 5 - cd user_guide_src

Step 6 - make html (here i have a problem. i get a message saying.. 'make' it not recognized as an internal or external command)

To run easy_instal like on other steps, i added "C:\Python27\Scripts" into Path environment variable. But i don't know how to do same thing for 'make' command to be available.

Step 6 is the only thing it's missing, all others ran successfuly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added "C:\Python27\Scripts" into Path environment variable
    sphinx-build -b html c:\wamp\www\codeigniter\user_guide_src\source c:\wamp\www\codeigniter\user_guide_html
should work.

Full tutorial I had used in my case was from [Compile CodeIgniter User Guide on Windows](http://www.reloadedpc.com/code-igniter/compile-codeigniter-user-guide-windows/)
which were the same steps as yours.